# How to limit teams view to just their own assignments

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I have a google sheet work order page set up. The columns are:

ID No., Title, Description, Location, Crew Assigned, Date Assigned, Hours Worked, Work Description.

Crew Assigned are pulled from a dropdown populated by a second sheet. So the entry is standardized.

I want the crew, when they open up the work order sheet, to see only the rows that are assigned to them. They would then enter Hours Worked, and the Work Description. They use apple mobile devices exclusively.

Is there a best practice for this type of work delegation within sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have one master spreadsheet and then to each team give a new spreadsheet with `FILTER(IMPORTRANGE(...` formula.